# First impressions redux

Tags: word, rhyme, steganography, seasonal

> Once upon a time,
>   a child wrote a rhyme.
>   It asked for the way,
>   you can date this day,
>   if we know the moon,
>   and its springtime tune.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@Amit Naidu](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4318/amit-naidu) has already given a good explanation for why the hidden answer is what it is; please give [their answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/63109) your upvotes too.

As for the [steganography](/questions/tagged/steganography) aspect:

> The answer is hidden in the lines of the poem.
>  It can be found by looking at the first word of each line, counting the number of letters in it,
>  and then taking the $n^{th}$ letter of the $n^{th}$ word of each line:
>
>  `Once upon a time,`  $\hspace{8.5ex}$ **E**    *Once* = 4 letters; 4th letter of 4th word ("tim**e**") = E
>  `a child wrote a rhyme.`  $\hspace{4ex}$ **A**    *a* = 1 letter; 1st letter of 1st word ("**a**") = A
>  `It asked for the way,`  $\hspace{5ex}$ **S**    *It* = 2 letters; 2nd letter of 2nd word ("a**s**ked") = S
>  `you can date this day,`  $\hspace{4ex}$ **T**    *you* = 3 letters; 3rd letter of 3rd word ("da**t**e") = T
>  `if we know the moon,`  $\hspace{5.7ex}$ **E**    *if* = 2 letters; 2nd letter of 2nd word ("w**e**") = E
>  `and its springtime tune.`  $\hspace{2ex}$ **R**    *and* = 3 letters; 3rd letter of 3rd word ("sp**r**ingtime") = R

And so we have our answer confirmed at last.

Comment: Ah, well done! I could clearly see those letters of Easter sitting in that rhyme, but the scheme eluded me. I kept trying to make sense out of 4-1-4-9-4-9. The check mark belongs here.

Comment: This post uses steg,
to crack out the egg.
So let me embark,
with no more remark,
to strike the checkmark!

Answer (score 8):

You must be talking about:

> Easter, because it is Easter weekend and its date in the Gregorian calendar is based on the spring equinox and the ecclesiastical full moon.
>
>   I couldn't find the referenced child, but here is the rhyme by English poet Justin Richardson (1900-1975):
>
> `No need for confusion if we but recall
> That Easter on the first Sunday after the full moon following the vernal equinox doth fall.`
>
>  There is a similar [Scottish poem](http://www.rampantscotland.com/poetry/blpoems_easter.htm) too, but it does not employ the vernal equinox as its reference.

Comment: Impressive first post, but to count on the checkmark, the [steganography](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/steganography/info) tag needs applied to show the hidden word.